# Jindal Vijaynagar Share Certificate

Tags: india, share-certificate

I have a physical share certificate of Jindal Vijaynagar which was bought in the name of my mother in 1995.  I believe this company is now known as Jindal Steel.  How can I get the share converted for the current company?  What will be the current value?  What is the process?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE.  On this site, typing in ALL CAPS is discouraged, so please turn the caps lock off on your keyboard before you post again.  I have edited your post to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's very simple process:

1. Open a demat account with a broker like ICICI direct, Zeodha, Sharekhan etc
2. Then fill DRF which is dematerialisation request form and after that you can surrender your physical certificates.
3. Then your broker will sends a request  to Register and transfer agent and then they will verify the physical documents along with details.
4. Then register and transfer agent will ask the respective company to make the amendment and after the confirmation from the company the shares will be credited to your account.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question, but on Jindal Steel's [investor page](https://www.jindalsteelpower.com/investors/investors.html) they list the [contact information for their Investor Relations Team](https://www.jindalsteelpower.com/investors/company-secretary-for-general-queries.html).  They should be able to tell you if your share certificate can be transferred to stock in their company and how many shares you would receive.

Alternatively, a broker should be able to figure it out and tell you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Open a demat account in your mother's name. This can be opened at any Bank or financial institution. They also offer service of converting the physical share to demat. They should also be able to tell confirm about Jindal Steel.